# Do affine spaces have coordinate transformations?

Tags: vector-spaces, coordinate-systems, affine-geometry

I asked a question on Physics SE and there seemed to be some confusion as to whether affine spaces could have coordinate transformations. Specifically, the particular space I was working with was $\Bbb{R} \times \Bbb{R}^3$, which gives us $(t,\mathbf{x})$. This space usually involves transformations of the form $g: (t,\mathbf{x}) \rightarrow (t + s,G\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{v}t + \mathbf{s})$. The particular space in question (Galilean space) can physically also be described by an affine space $A^4$ and my question was if there was an analog to $g$ on the affine space itself. But to answer this, seemingly I need to first establish if affine spaces can have coordinate transformations like the one I just did.

**My Question**

Can an affine space have coordinate transformations? If so, please provide an example.

Comment: Sorry I'm late, I came to this looking for solid movements... Of course you have affine transformations, see e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/a/584315/259671